# Error on deploy my app to heroku

Tags: php, heroku, deployment

I'm having problems when I try to deploy my application on heroku. I've tried to exec the command on dyno bash, but does not exists files in de /app folder.

```
git push heroku master

Counting objects: 1716, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1650/1650), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1716/1716), 13.58 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1716 (delta 376), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Resolved composer.lock requirement for PHP to version 5.5.20.
remote: -----> Installing system packages...
remote:        - PHP 5.5.20
remote:        - Apache 2.4.10
remote:        - Nginx 1.6.0
remote: -----> Installing PHP extensions...
remote:        - redis (composer.lock; downloaded)
remote:        - mongo (composer.lock; downloaded)
remote:        - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: File '/composer.phar' isn't executable; please 'chmod +x'!
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-app.
remote:
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Any update on this issue? Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution of this. 
Actually composer.phar need only first time. so just remove it from local and run

```
git add .
git commit -m 'composer.phar removed'
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I've tried to remove composer.phar but the error still persist! :/

Answer (score 0):

> remote:  !     ERROR: File '/composer.phar' isn't executable; please 'chmod +x'!

You need to update file permissions.

Comment: On dyno or my local file? I've tried to update file permissions on server (dyno), but i don't see any files in /app folder.